# How to handle grub when adding new system and removing old one?

Tags: installation, upgrade, grub

I want to upgrade my Proxmox cluster from 2.2 to 4.
I think I have this well thought, but there's one thing I am not sure of.

Currently, my installation runs on LVM A. I have added few new disks and created LVM B. I would like to install the new system on LVM B, migrate the virtual servers there and only after I make sure everything works [it's kind of a big leap] I will want to salvage the old drives.

After installing the new system, I understand that I will be editing the `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` file on the old system in order to be able to boot the new installation.
Once everything works, how do I move the config to the new installation and ensure that it works after I remove the old drives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GRUB's configuration is actually in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` created by `grub-mkconfig` from the configuration files in `/etc/grub.d/`. See GRUB [Simple configuration](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Simple-configuration.html#Simple-configuration).

You can install GRUB to the new drive (say `/dev/sdb`) by booting into the operating system in there. From that OS, install GRUB with:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdb
```

If that doesn't work directly and you get errors, proceed with:

```
sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sdb
sudo update-grub
```

Finally get GRUB to remember where it should reinstall on updates. Choose the correct drive in:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
```

Comment: thank you very much! I just wanted to be sure I won't mess up my configs.